# LSZ formula in Srednicki, normalization issue

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, renormalization, s-matrix-theory, normalization

In the Ch.5 of his [book](https://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Emark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf), Srednicki says LSZ formula is valid provided the following conditions hold:

$$
\langle 0|\phi(x)|0\rangle = 0, \langle p|\phi(x)|0\rangle = 1
$$

To achieve these conditions, he manipulates the Lagrangian and obtains

$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2}Z\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi + ...
$$

I found that this manipulation alters the normalization of creation/annihilation operators, which are defined by $a^{\dagger}(k) = -i \int d^3x e^{ikx}\stackrel{\leftrightarrow}{\partial_0}\phi(x)$.
Indeed, with the Lagrangian above, $\Pi = Z\dot{\phi}$. The canonical commutation relations leads to

$$
[a(\vec{k},t), a^{\dagger}(\vec{k},t)] = \frac{1}{Z}(2\pi)^32\omega\delta^3(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')
$$

Questions:

- Should I redefine the creation/annihilation operators according to the above result, namely, $a_{new} = \sqrt{Z} a_{old}$?
- Alternatively, should I impose $\langle p|p'\rangle = \frac{1}{Z}(2\pi)^32E\delta^3(\vec{p}-\vec{p}')$?
- Or.. does the relation $|p\rangle = a^{\dagger}(p)|0\rangle $ even hold?
- I think the condition $\langle p|\phi(0)|0\rangle = 1$ must be changed according to answers of the above questions. If I am right, how do I understand later chapters of Srednicki in which $\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2}Z\partial^\mu \phi \partial_\mu \phi + ...$ and $
  \langle p|\phi(0)|0\rangle = 1$ are both used?